# Fragment with getsupportFragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a case to replace fragment of type  `android.app.Fragment` not of type `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`  &  cannot change its type as i imported it from gradle  and use `getSupportFragmentManager()`  at the same time is that possible ?

Comment: I don't think it is posible, but there is no reason why you can't switch to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` completely

Comment: as it it is built in library used in gradle not my own implementation

Comment: I don't generally advise mixing framework and support `Fragment`s and other classes, but you do still have access to the framework `FragmentManager` in an `AppCompatActivity` through `getFragmentManager()`. If you're wanting to replace a support `Fragment` with a framework one, or vice versa, you'll have to handle the `remove()` and `add()` calls separately, each with the appropriate `FragmentManager`.

Comment: if you have to use `android.app.Fragment` because of the library, then you have to use it in entire app I think. Just use `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`